# Logout user session automatically in codeigniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I am making an admin panel web-based app based on CI 3.0.4. So, if a user is logged in as administrator, but if at the same time super user changed that user from admin to normal user then they should be logged out immediately.

Problem here is I am storing data in session, if I will not then I need to run db query every time which will put too much db load on application.

Anyway we could logout user session or update user's session value as soon as they are changed. If we are able to update those then my app will check and logout.

Same as google does't with gmail. If you are logged in from multiple devices, you can logout other device instances.

Please suggest some logic or best method to handle such situations.

Comment: if you are using session with database then I guess you can do it by deleting the entry for that particular user from the sessions table.

Comment: @AdeshPandey but using session via database will make the application heavy and impact performance as well. Any other way?

Comment: You should ask your self what is frequency of changing this session or how many times administrator would change session level. I don't see any reason against one `if then else` control check in logout method that would update session in DB when this kind of action occures.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manipulate a piece of data that you're currently storing inside a session, then it shouldn't be stored in there in the first place.

Trying to read and/or change another user's session data may be the immediate thought, because it's easier to store a "logged-in" flag inside the session itself. However, doing that is wrong and not as easy as it sounds in the first place.
Session data is designed to be read by one user and one user only, and because of the way PHP serializes session data, it is borderline impossible to ignore that fact.

Contrary to others' comments, changing the driver to 'database' won't help either. It's the serialization format that's making this hard, not the storage.

The actual solution would be to somehow store the `sessionId <-> userId` relation outside of the session itself, so you can later erase all sessions that belong to the user who's permissions you've just modified.
A relational database does make this trivial, indeed, but you can use any kind of storage for that.

Answer (score -1):

for this situation if you are not close to finish your project [ion auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) is a good solution . it has groups options and you can check if user is admin or not in __constract function. something like this

```
public function __construct()
  {
    if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {$this->ion_auth->logout();die();}
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
```

Comment: But internally how it works, doesn't it run db query on each run to check it is an admin or not?

Comment: no it do not run a db query. it runs on time and keep it in session. @Prashant

Comment: So, if Admin1 is logged in already and "Super User" modified Admin1's permission and removed his admin permission, so will Admin1 will be logged out automatically whenever he will access any page?

Comment: not exatly. for tahtyou also need to clear session file of user. for a live system there are too much session files and their name do not include username or id. only inside session file you can find user info . it looks something like this file name :`ci_sessiona662a2a8b4fc7e66221ff8a691284fb6fa31450c` and inside file: `__ci_last_regenerate|i:1453579910;identity|s:17:"synan54@gmail.com";email|s:17:"synan54@gmail.com";user_id|s:1:"1";old_last_login|s:10:"1453567741";` @Prashant

Comment: but if you change session time something close like 10 minute inside config.php file `$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;`  10 min later he needs to relogin and he will be disabled. changing an admin is not something a superadmin do too much you can also try to clear all session files